# How to distribute undefined attributes of a class to a list of other objects

Tags: python

I have a class that contains a list of other objects (all of the same type). Whenever I call an attribute that is undefined in my ObjectList class I want the call to get distributed to all "child" objects, like this:

```
class ObjectList(object):
  def __init__(self, child_objects):
    self.child_objects = child_objects

ol = ObjectList([a, b, c])

ol.foo('bar')
# I now want that foo('bar') is called in every child object, like:
# a.foo('bar')
# b.foo('bar')
# c.foo('bar')
# I don't know the name of "foo" beforehand
```

I can't figure out if this is possible. The background for this is that there is code that before only called one object and now needs to call a list of objects of the same type. I don't want to change all the code surrounding the object to work with lists now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class ObjectList:


    def __init__(self, child_objects):
        self.child_objects = child_objects


    def __getattr__(self, name):
        def looper(*args, **kwargs):
            for obj in self.child_objects:
                attr = getattr(obj, name)
                attr(*args, **kwargs)
        return looper





class Obj:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}({})'.format(type(self).__name__, self.data)

    def foo(self, arg):
        print('Object', self, 'called with', arg)


ol = ObjectList([Obj('a'), Obj('b'), Obj('c'),])

ol.foo('bar')
```

You can handle the assignment case similarly with `__setattr__`.

Answer (score 0):

`__getattr__` is the method that is called when you access a nonexistent attribute on an object. You can define that to call the same attribute on the children:

```
class ObjectList(object):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return [getattr(child, name) for child in self.child_objects]
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot a special case, this also needs to work for attribute assignments like ol.x = y. This does not seem to work with __getattr__.